# Confused on why not store access token in local storage

Tags: reactjs, authentication, security, authorization, okta

I have an application that uses react to authenticate. With the Okta library, it by default stores the id token and access token in the local storage. I then grab the access token to make an .net api call that is protected by role authorization.

I'm having difficulty understand the issue with XSS attack. My understanding is that they can inject javascript code to do something with the access token. They are only able to get their own access token by logging in normally. Why is it an issue if they are doing something with their own access token? In addition, can't the access token be found in the network call, so it's not really hidden to begin with?

Can anyone provide me with an example or explain the gaps in my logic? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the access token here will be stored in the browser (I'm not super clear on the differences between cookies and local storage but correct me if I'm wrong). When you do that .NET API call the browser knows to pass along the access token. The issue is that websites can include arbitrary JavaScript that runs on your browser, i.e. that arbitrary JavaScript can execute HTTPS requests from your browser using your access token.

In this way, the malicious agent wouldn't be creating their own access token, but instead using yours in arbitrary ways that might give them access to whatever private data you have stored behind your .NET API.

The avoid this, we limit the domains that can access our APIs. Typically, you might see APIs only allow requests from the same domain name. For example: if you API is accessible at `mywebsite.com/api` then it would only allow API requests from `mywebsite.com`.

edit:

Forgot to answer the "isn't the access token not hidden because it's included in a public HTTPS request" question. There's a couple of potential solutions here. On websites that use TLS (i.e. you're accessing with HTTPS), you know the public key of the website you're intending to send data to. You can use that public key to encrypt your access token and only the website will be able to decrypt it (with their private key). This way, your access token is kept secret between you and the .NET API.

Comment: I just watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbmBDiR6WaY, which I think cleared some of my misunderstanding. I believe the point is as you mentioned that the attacker would be using stolen access token. 

In my example, if the attacker are able to store a script in the db, which would then be retreived and ran on a victim user browser, the script would run and send the access token from the local storage to the attacker, which he can then use to impersonate.

Comment: Okay great that YouTube video is helpful glad it cleared things up. Does the solution where you limit API calls to trusted domains (i.e. `mydomain.com`) make sense? In other words, does it make sense how it limits malicious agents on other domains from using your session token to access the API?

Comment: I'm not clear on that part. My understanding is that the attacker can obtain the victim's cookie via XSS attack. And wouldn't stealing the cookie mean the attacker can log into mywebsite.com via the cookie (impersonating the user) and still send an api to mywebsite.com/api on the victim's behalf? It's the exact same scenario as the youtube video if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: In XSS I don't think the actually steals your access token. The access token is stored in your browser, but when you access `mydomain.com` your browser knows to include the access token in that HTTPS request (this is just how cookies work). But say the attack has their own website `malicioussite.com`. If you visit `malicioussite.com` there could be some JavaScript that essentially says "make an HTTPS request to `mydomain.com` that deletes my account". Because the request is coming from your browser (where that `malicioussite.com` JavaScript is executed), the browser includes your access token.

Comment: I think I need to do more research on how this all works. I will use your explanation as I go through. But appreciate you taking the time to explain. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In an XSS attack there is nothing that prevents the attacker from reading values in local storage. Unless there are countermeasures such as CSP to prevent exfiltration, an XSS attack can be used to steal access tokens.

When cookies have the HttpOnly flag set they are not accessible by script. The browser will attach them on relevant requests as intended.

When requests are encrypted using HTTPS the headers will be encrypted and thus hidden.